# Google oAuth2 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No refresh token is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, es6-promise

This below is my auth.js route code to login via oAuth2 and it was working till this afternoon, now tonight started to throw error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No refresh token is set.`

```
const express = require("express");

const google = require('googleapis').google;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const CONFIG = require("../config/passport-google");

const nf = require('node-fetch');
const gUser = require('../models/User-g');

const router = express.Router();

// Google's OAuth2 client
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

router.get("/youtube", function(req, res) {
  // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Obtain the google login link to which we'll send our users to give us access
  const loginLink = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline", // Indicates that we need to be able to access data continously without the user constantly giving us consent
    scope: CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.scopes // Using the access scopes from our config file
  });
  return res.render("./home/g-login", { loginLink: loginLink });
});

router.get("/youtube/callback", function(req, res) {
  // Create an OAuth2 client object from the credentials in our config file
  const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_id,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.client_secret,
    CONFIG.oauth2Credentials.redirect_uris[0]
  );

  if (req.query.error) {
    // The user did not give us permission.
    return res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) return res.redirect("/");

      // Store the credentials given by google into a jsonwebtoken in a cookie called 'jwt'
      res.cookie("jwt", jwt.sign(token, CONFIG.JWTsecret));
      
      // return res.redirect("/get_some_data");

      if (!req.cookies.jwt) {
        // We haven't logged in
        return res.redirect("/");
      }
    
      // Add this specific user's credentials to our OAuth2 client
      oauth2Client.credentials = jwt.verify(req.cookies.jwt, CONFIG.JWTsecret);
    
      // Get the youtube service
      const service = google.youtube("v3");

      const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${token[Object.keys(token)[0]]}`;

      const get_data = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await nf(url);
          const json = await response.json();

          // save user to db
          async (json, done) => {
            const newUser = {
              channelId: json.id,
              channelEmail: json.email,
              image: json.picture,
              createdAt: Date.now()
            }
            try {
              let user = await gUser.findOne({ channelId: json.id });
              if(user){
                done(null, user);
              } else {
                user = await gUser.create(newUser);
                done(null, user);
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return res.redirect("../../500");
            }
          }

          return json;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.redirect("../../500");
        }
      };
    
      // Get 50 of the user's subscriptions (the channels they're subscribed to)
      service.subscriptions
        .list({
          auth: oauth2Client,
          mine: true,
          part: "snippet,contentDetails",
          maxResults: 50
        })
        .then(async (response) => {
        //.then(response => {
          const diomerda = await get_data();

          // Render the profile view, passing the subscriptions to it
          return res.render("./user/dashboard", { subscriptions: response.data.items, diomerda: diomerda });
        });

    });
  }
});

// Logout from Google
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to delete the app from the authorized apps inside my google account im using to test, and when i test the login again it now goes through all the steps of the login, it asks for permit, i accept twice and then it throws that error and the page looks like frozen in a loop

Comment: put a `.catch` on the `service.subscriptions.list` promise and logout the error - that seems to be the only place you don't handle a promise rejection - assuming the error is on the server side of course

Comment: thank you i missed that, now it works